# Print upside down triangle using a nested loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

The triangle I am wanting to print looks like this:

```
123456
23456
3456
456
56
6
```

So far I've been printing:

```
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Here the code I've come up with:

```
System.out.println();
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++)
{
  for (int j=7; j>i; j--)
  {
    System.out.print(j - 1);
  }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close. Note the start index of the inner loop needs to change each time. How about:

```
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++) {
    for (int j=i; j<=6; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going the wrong direction on the inner for loop.

```
System.out.println();

for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    for(int j = i; j <= 6; j++){
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

By setting j equal to i in the inner for loop, the line will shift forward one on it's own.

Output:

```
123456
23456
3456
456
56
6
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {


for(int i=1;i<7;i++){
for(int j=i;j<7;j++)
    System.out.print(j);

System.out.println("");
}

}
}
```

Edits: Let's consider what each loop iteration does.
       The outer loop sees to it that all the values are printed before heading to the next line. But, how do you print the required values?

This is done by the inner loop. It starts the printing of the values from value of i in the present iteration to the value n (Here n=6). So, in first iteration, the values would be 123456. In second (& in the next line) the values start printing from 2 i.e., 23456 and so on. And that's your required pattern.

Comment: This answer would be better if you provided some commentary as to how and why it answers the question.